# Image zoom is not proper

Tags: android, image, zooming

I want to pinch zoom an image but problem is when I zoom it does not zoom in and out from where my fingers are. It goes to point 0, 0.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

    Log.e("ScaleFactor", "" + mScaleFactor);

    // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
    mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.4f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
    if(mScaleFactor>=1)
        mScaleFactor=1f;

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

I tried a lot but could get any way to fix this.

Comment: pls go through the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977138/android-multi-touch-zooming

Comment: I am mot loading the image from resources, i am making a relationship drawing on my canvas. i have to zoom that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9652985/1181992 try this link...

Answer (score 0):

it is useful

```
private float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
private float maxZoom;
private float minZoom;
private float height;
private float width;
private RectF viewRect; 


private void init() {
    maxZoom = 4;
    minZoom = 0.25f;
    height = myimage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight()+20;
    width = myimage.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()+20;
    viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, myimage.getWidth()+20, myimage.getHeight()+20);
}
```

Comment: My application is to draw relationship diagram i have to zoom in and out that drawing which i have drawn on Canvas.